# storing data from the basket in the session (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple shopping basket. The first div adds item to the cart, the secound div removes the item from the cart.

After refreshing the browser, the products in the cart disappear. How do you keep this data in session?

```
$(document).on("click", ".addtobasket", function () {

    $("#kontener_koszyka").fadeIn();

    var nazwa = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.nazwa').text();
    var cena = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.cenaprzedmiotu').text();

    var suma = 0;

    var li = "<li class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>" + nazwa + "</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>" + cena + " zł</span><span style='float: right; margin-right: 30px;' class='deleteitembasket'><i class=\"fas fa-times\"></i></span></li>";

    $("#koszyk").append(li);

    $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function () {
        suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });

    $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on('click', '.deleteitembasket', function () {

    var nazwa = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.nazwa').text();
    var cena = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.cenaprzedmiotu').text();

    var suma = 0;

    var li = "<li class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>" + nazwa + "</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>" + cena + " zł</span><span style='float: right; margin-right: 30px;' class='deleteitembasket'><i class=\"fas fa-times\"></i></span></li>";

    $(this).closest("li").remove();

    $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function () {
        suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });

    $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
});
```

EDIT:
this code stores data in the session, but when I try to delete a single element li, it deletes the entire list.

```
$(document).on("click", ".addtobasket", function () {

        $("#kontener_koszyka").fadeIn();

        var nazwa = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.nazwa').text();
        var cena = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.cenaprzedmiotu').text();

        var suma = 0;

        var li = "<li class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>" + nazwa + "</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>" + cena + " zł</span><span style='float: right; margin-right: 30px;' class='deleteitembasket'><i class=\"fas fa-times\"></i></span></li>";

        $("#koszyk").append(li);

        localStorage.setItem('itemlist', (localStorage.getItem('itemlist') || '') + li);

        $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function () {
            suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
        });

        $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
        localStorage.setItem('sumalist', suma.toFixed(2));
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.deleteitembasket', function () {

        var nazwa = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.nazwa').text();
        var cena = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.cenaprzedmiotu').text();

        var suma = 0;

        var li = "<li class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>" + nazwa + "</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>" + cena + " zł</span><span style='float: right; margin-right: 30px;' class='deleteitembasket'><i class=\"fas fa-times\"></i></span></li>";

        $(this).closest("li").remove();
        /* this line remove all items in localStorage. */ localStorage.removeItem('itemlist', (localStorage.getItem('itemlist') || '') + li);

        $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function () {
            suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
        });

        $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
        localStorage.setItem('sumalist', suma.toFixed(2));
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem('itemlist') != null) {
        $("#koszyk").append(localStorage.getItem('itemlist'));
        $("#cena span").text(localStorage.getItem('sumalist'));
    }
```

Comment: have you tried using localStorage?

Comment: yes, but it removed all elements from the li list when I needed to delete only (this) item.

Comment: if you want to persist data before refreshing the browser you'd need to use localStorage. show some code of what you've done with localStorage so we can help

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take into consideration that localStorage stores a key-value pair.
So, when you are storing **itemlist** and **somalist**, their value will be overwritten if they were stored already.

For this you have a couple of solutions:

- You can save every item with an unique key
- You can save a [stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) object, and [parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) it when you are getting it.

The one I like the most is the object one. So every time you have to add or remove something for your localStorage you get the object (string), parse it, do the modifications you need and save it again.

Hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: Lobo, I don't know how to do the modifications I need.

Comment: Have you tried what I've said? is there something you don't understand?

Comment: I do not understand how to do it.

Comment: what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: I tried You can item with an unique key. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't have your entire code to guess that... probably you have some unique key on your items, like the name, id or something. It'd be way easier to help if you post a working snippet with all your code.

Comment: JV, I have a unique key for all items. But I don't know, whats now?